# Parse Python List to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I have an array that has  values separated by '|'. I would like to parse it to a pandas data frame.

```
import pandas as pd    
arr = ['19345360853|5264654|100530|2017-01-07', '19345360853|13518371|100530|2018-10-08']
pd.DataFrame([{'Id': item.split('|')[0] ,'Code_A': item.split('|')[1] , 'Code_B': item.split('|')[2],'Reg_Date': item.split('|')[3]} for item in arr ])
```

I would like the pandas dataframe to be in the following schema,

'Id' string
'Code_A' string
'Code_B' string
'Reg_Date' date

So the resulting Pandas dataframe would be similar to this.
[result dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSBBv.png)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Python does not have arrays, python has lists. That said, why not just split the strings by `|` separator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, convert to two dimensional list

```
arr = [a.split("|") for a in arr]
```

Second, convert to pandas dataframe

```
data = pd.DataFrame(arr,columns=['Id','Code_A','Code_B','Reg_Date'])

            Id    Code_A  Code_B    Reg_Date
0  19345360853   5264654  100530  2017-01-07
1  19345360853  13518371  100530  2018-10-08
```

Convert column Reg_Date using `astype` (Ref: [astype](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html))

```
a =pd.DataFrame(arr,columns=['Id','Code_A','Code_B','Reg_Date'])
a['Reg_Date'] = a['Reg_Date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

Comment: How to get the Reg_Date column as date?

Comment: @KeerikkattuChellappan using astype, i edit the answer

Comment: Just to note, you can make the `[a.split("|") for a in arr]` into  a generator comprehension and it won't take up as much space in memory.