# Web scraping to excel, misalignment of text (selenium, python)

Tags: python, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i'm trying to webscrape to excel, but i can't get the list of courses to actually align properly. it is just one long string on one row. i would like each row for every course to be under the proper category (see image for reference).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import re
import csv

driver = webdriver.Chrome("drivers/chromedriver")

# driver.get("https://web3.ncaa.org/hsportal/exec/hsAction")

driver.get("https://web3.ncaa.org/hsportal/exec/hsAction")
Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "state")))).select_by_visible_text("New Hampshire")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='city']").send_keys("Moultonborough")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='name']").send_keys("Moultonborough Academy")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Search']").click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='hsCode']"))).click()

x = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//tr[th[@class='header']])[1]/th")
head = [re.sub('\s+',' ',el.text) for el in x]
y =  = ([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table#approvedCourseTable_1 td")))])

with open('out.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(head)
    writer.writerow(courses)
```

currently it looks like this: [image]

but would like it like this: [image]

Comment: What are you using as separator character?

Comment: i guess i don't know enough about separator characters, so i'll look into that. i'd appreciate any pointers or direction if possible. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty of using a different library. If you really need a csv output, then it should be easy enough to tweak the pandas bit to serve your needs. You can use [to_csv().](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

```
main_table = driver.find_element_by_id("NcaaCrs_ApprovedCategory_All")  # Parent table.
titles = iter([title.text for title in main_table.find_elements_by_class_name("hs_tableHeader")][1:])  # Get titles above the tables, ignoring the general title in the first entry.

tables = main_table.find_elements_by_tag_name("table[id*=approvedCourseTable")  # Find all tables by partial id.
tables_html = "\n".join([table.get_attribute('outerHTML') for table in tables])  # Combine html of all tables.
tables_df = pd.read_html(tables_html)  # Creates a list of table DataFrames.

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("temp.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')

for table_df in tables_df:  # Loop through DataFrames
    title = next(titles).replace("/", "-")  # Select next title and clean it up for excel sheet name.
    table_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=title, index=False)  # Send DataFrame to writer on individual sheet.
writer.save()  # Save Excel file.
```

Hope it achieves what it was supposed to.